# How to make django admin site support non-standard American English characters

Tags: django

Is there a way for admin site to support special characters like ó á ¿?, etc ?
Every time I want to update a textfield, using the admin site, containing nonEnglish characters I get 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf'

Is there a way to change that?

Edit 1: adding details
Model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
```

And Question is register on admin.site, so when I want to save a text similar to "¿Cúal fue la descripción?" and click on Save I get error page with message:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf'
```

Comment: Can you add some more context as to where you are getting problems? Django has excellent internationalisation support, so I'd be curious to see how this error is arising.

Comment: Sure, I added some more detail

Comment: Yes, just posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had to add this to my model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.question)
```